# How do i extend the container / body behind the bottombar so i can get rid of the white corners?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get rid of these white corners
i have tried what i could have find on online even have the extendBody set as true for this one but it still is not working

[image]

this is the page

```
class _DietPageState extends State<DietPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.vitgreen,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
        extendBody: true,
        body: Container(
          color: AppColors.vitgreen,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is how the bottomNavBar is set up

```
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.Primebg,
          appBar: appbar,
          body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.Primebg,
              border: Border.all(color: AppColors.line, width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              child: GNav(
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  _navigateBottomBar(index);
                },
                haptic: true, // haptic feedback
                tabBorderRadius: 50,
                tabActiveBorder: Border.all(color: AppColors.litegrey, width: 1), // tab button border
                curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart, // tab animation curves
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), // tab animation duration
                gap: 5,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                iconSize: 30,
                color: AppColors.darkgrey,
                activeColor: AppColors.whiteText,
                tabBackgroundColor: AppColors.vitred,
```

i tried using extendBody didnt worked , i am thought it will make sure the body extends far enough to cover those corners

Comment: can you simplify the widget that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked your code and i think you put the bottomnavbar scaffold color with the same color as the container color, you can try to change this inside of you bottomnavbar code

```dart
   return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.Primebg, // THIS PART
          appBar: appbar,
          body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.Primebg,
              border: Border.all(color: AppColors.line, width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              child: GNav(
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  _navigateBottomBar(index);
                },
                haptic: true, // haptic feedback
                tabBorderRadius: 50,
                tabActiveBorder: Border.all(color: AppColors.litegrey, width: 1), // tab button border
                curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart, // tab animation curves
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), // tab animation duration
                gap: 5,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                iconSize: 30,
                color: AppColors.darkgrey,
                activeColor: AppColors.whiteText,
                tabBackgroundColor: AppColors.vitred,
```

> backgroundColor: AppColors.Primebg, // THIS PART

into this

```dart
backgroundColor: AppColors.vitgreen,
```

and I don't know why your bottomnavbar design look like that. i suggest you to made something like this, and this is just suggestion  for you

```dart
class BottomNavScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "/Bottom-nav-screen";
  const BottomNavScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavScreen> createState() => _BottomNavScreenState();
}

class _BottomNavScreenState extends State<BottomNavScreen> {
  final List _pages = [
    const HomeScreen(),
    const LiveScreen(),
    const FeedsScreen(),
    const CartScreen(),
    const ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  _onTap(int i) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = i;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pages[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: _onTap,
        selectedItemColor: primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
        unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
            label: "Live",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed),
            icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed_outlined),
            label: "Feeds",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
            label: "Cart",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
            label: "Me",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to change the design with responsive bottom icon. you can just recreate the `BottomNavigationBarItem` widget into your design